# How connect the coordinate and fill the area to create a binary mask?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, smoothing

I need to create a binary mask from a series of coordinates. My current code is shown below but the edges of the resulting image are not smooth. I think it is not precise and I need to make sure I am connecting exact coordinate and connect them together.

Here on the left side, I plotted the points (always 42 points) and on the right side is the output of the code. As you can see the edges are not smooth. 
[image]
Here is the current code and the output: ([coordinates are attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GrrWRYEjVsmzp2ejtLIkNuVPHQp8l9DU/view?usp=sharing))

`im` is an image of size 112 x 112, filled with zero everywhere except the `X`, `Y` coordinates and inside the region filled with the 255.

```
function BW = mask_data(X,Y, im)
X = round(X);
Y = round(Y);
%round coordinates
X ( X < 1 ) = 1;
Y ( Y < 1 ) = 1;
BW = im > 255;
for p = 1:length(X)

   BW(Y(p),X(p)) = 1;
end

BW = BW * 255;
BW = bwconvhull(BW);
BW = im2uint8(BW);
figure;
imshow(BW);
close all;
end
```

Comment: The right hand side image obviously does _not_ seem to be the filled version of the left hand side dotted image. Does this example actually demonstrate how the code is supposed to behave?

Comment: Also what your exact question and/or problem here? Does your current method fail for certain cases? Would you only like to smooth the resulting image?

Comment: @User81862311 Yes, you are right. The example was not good, so I did edit the post with the new example.

Comment: The question is how can I provide a mask with the coordinates which is more precise than "bwconvhull". Yes, I need to be smooth.

Comment: Why do you expect the edges to be smooth? Why do you think that makes the mask more "precise"? What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the union convex hull is still your best bet. If you have images that are actually comprised of a single object then your shown algorithm should work just fine, though you are doing some redundant steps in your shown code. If that is not the case, then you may want to consider finding the convex hull of multiple components through adding the `objects` option to your `bwconvhull` call. If you strongly believe that the results are "not precise" then you may want to show an example image in which the algorithm actually fails.

As per the results not being smooth, you should logically not expect smooth boundaries for an image of size 112 x 112 with an object boundary similar to what you have shown. However, I would simply smooth the results if smooth images are preferred:

```
originalImage = imread('Adrress\to\your\image.png');
% To have the same image size as yours
originalImage = imresize(originalImage, [112 112]);
% Create a binary image
binaryImage = im2bw(originalImage);

% Create a binary convex hull image
UnionCH = bwconvhull(binaryImage);

% Smooth the results (note the change of binary class)
% Second arg (0.7) is the std dev of the Gaussian smoothing kernel
SmoothUnionCH = imgaussfilt(single(UnionCH), 0.7);

figure
subplot(131)
imshow(binaryImage)
title('Binary Image')
subplot(132)
imshow(UnionCH)
title('Binary Convex Hull Image')
subplot(133)
imshow(SmoothUnionCH,[])
title('Smooth Convex Hull Image')
```

You can adjust the size of the smoothing kernel of course. The results for the code above:

[image: Results of the convex hull image]